# Не выводит контент в WebView

Tags: java, javafx, webview

В контроллере: `@FXML private WebView yaMapWeb = new WebView();`

Метод старт:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    //yaMapWeb.getEngine().load(getClass().getResource("/com/example/demo/yaMap.html").toExternalForm());
    yaMapWeb.getEngine().load("https://google.com");
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("storeMap-window.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(yaMapWeb, 600, 400);
    scene.setRoot(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Магазины по близости");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

В fxml:

```
<WebView layoutX="100.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="272.0" prefWidth="448.0" fx:id="yaMapWeb"/>
```

Почему-то не выводит сайт гугл в webView элемент, но если сделать вывод на все окно, то все выводит, а мне надо именно в компонент webview

Вот в белом прямоугольнике webView и вывод нужен сюда

[image: Вот в белом прямоугольнике webView и вывод нужен сюда]

Answer (score 0):

В конструкторе вы устанавливаете WebView как root, но потом меняете его на другую панель root.
Уберите `scene.setRoot(root);`

Comment: Проблема решена,я писал код не в контроллере, написал в контроллере и все выводит